# how to use accented characters in jquery?

Tags: jquery, localization

I have two problems that probably have the same root cause and the same solution:

---

If I execute this code:

```
$("i").replaceInText("text1", "étrange");
```

I get **�trange** instead of **étrange**.

---

If I execute this code

```
$("i").replaceInText("étrange", "text1");
```

it does not find the **étrange**

---

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what encoding does your page has? I think it could be solved with utf-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your .js file is not encoded in utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("i").replaceInText("text1", "&#232;trange");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should check your encoded-file type. You should set it to UTF-8 if you want to use accent. Generally, you should use UTF-8 :)