# Using jQuery to select an HTML option with a value that contains special characters

Tags: jquery, html, forms, character-encoding, special-characters

I have the following options inside a select element:

```
<option value="Azua">Azua</option>
<option value="Barahona">Barahona</option>
<option value="Dajabón">Dajab&#243;n</option>
```

When I execute the following jQuery, the select is updated without any problems:

```
$('form:visible .inpProvince').val('Barahona');
```

However, when I run the following the select is reset to the first option:

```
$('form:visible .inpProvince').val('Dajabón');
```

I assume this has to do with the accented 'o'. Any idea how I can overcome this problem?

Comment: not ideal - but make the `value` non accented string only ?

Comment: @ManseUK The values attribute is populated by a database with values that I am unable to change.

Comment: Ok - just an idea ...looking at the answer below - seems it works as expected anyhow!

Comment: Okay, it turns out it was the character encoding of the *HTML*. I don't know who to give credit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem could be the file encoding *(the file where the js is)*. See the answer to [how to use accented characters in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108203/how-to-use-accented-characters-in-jquery). This maybe some help [Converting files to UTF-8](http://docs.moodle.org/21/en/Converting_files_to_UTF-8).

Comment: I saved the file as UTF-8 and the problem is not resolved. Also, when I execute the code from the Firebug console the result is the same.

Comment: I'm giving Scoobler credit because he pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

The special character is not the problem.  You can see a working example using this method here:

http://jsfiddle.net/aMUQk/

I would say your problem lies somewhere else...

Comment: Is there some way I can configure my server to resemble this?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.4.2. When I set the the version to 1.3.2 in your jsfiddle example it still works: http://jsfiddle.net/aMUQk/1/

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking the problem is somewhere else.  Is it possible that you have mistyped something somewhere?  Are you positive the elements you are executing against are the ones being displayed on the page?